# SSO Custom Button From VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on, custom

I have a custom login page created in visualforce for a community. I need to implement a button that will direct to SSO, I am currently just redirecting to the SSO login url from the Single-Sign-On settings. This directs me to a page with the Username/Pswd Field and a button that generates the SAML Request and takes the user to SSO. I wanted to know if there is a way to bypass this screen and just have a button on the custom login screen take me to the SSO page. I have been searching but cant seem to find any information out about this. The SSO is not set up as an Authentication Provider, it is just set up as the Single Sign-On for Salesforce. Do I have to manually create the AuthN request on my end?

The button on that page for the SSO Login has this html generated by SF:

```xml
<button class="button mb24 secondary wide" onclick="IdpOptions.useIdp('SSO Login', 'https://**.cs43.force.com/community/saml/authn-request.jsp?saml_request_id=********&amp;saml_acs=https%3A%2F%2F**.cs43.force.com%2Fcommunity%2Flogin%3Fso%3D**%26sc%3D**&amp;saml_binding_type=HttpRedirect&amp;Issuer=https%3A%2F%2F**.cs43.force.com%2Fcommunity&amp;samlSsoConfig=**&amp;RelayState=%2Fcommunity%2F');"><span>SSO Login</span></button>
```

Is there a way to recreate this on my visualforce custom login screen?

Comment: Use identity provider-initiated SSO. The corresponding URL attached to the button  can/should come from your identity provider

Comment: I dont think this is going to work. I can try, but we are trying to see if we can generate the SAML Request Id.